# How to add value to SET field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **user** with a field of type SET named **privs**.
The allowed values of this field are: 'ADD','EDIT',DELETE','ALL'.

What SQL query should I execute to add let's say value 'EDIT' to the field privs for a given row? But only if there is not already such a value.

**EDIT:**

I tried:
update user set
privs=concat(privs,'EDIT')

But I got an error:
**Data truncated for column 'privs' at row 1/**

And after that not all rows has EDIT value in its privs field.

Comment: Add unique constraint on privs field, it won't allow duplicate entries

Comment: I don't mean duplicates among different rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like MySQL is okay with adding a second `EDIT`.  It does, however, demand that the list is properly comma separated:

```
update  user
set     privs = concat(privs, if(length(privs)>0,',',''), 'EDIT')
where   id = 42
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6846f/1)

Comment: Here's SQL Fiddle link that works:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6846f/1   (The edit queue is full again.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the old values with the new one and then trim commas to manage the case of an old empty value.

```sql
UPDATE user
SET privs = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM CONCAT(privs, ',', 'EDIT'))
WHERE id = 123
```

Comment: Correct syntax of trim() is: TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM CONCAT(privs, ',', 'EDIT'))